# Unable to figure out why my code is printing "None". even though it should bring values

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to access S3 object and when i am printing the data objects, it prints "None" basically I am unable to move beyond that point since my "if" condition is failing. Could anyone please assist

```
if s3_resource.Bucket(s3_bucket).creation_date:
 print("UTKARSH")
```

Comment: Also, can anyone tell what "creation_date" does?

Answer (score 0):

this piece of code which you have specified is correct. Check whether you are able to access the object first and then go for if condition.

```
s3_object = boto.resource('s3').Bucket("Your Bucket Name")
```

or else you can also get the bucket info using s3 client like:

```
   busket_list = boto.client('s3').list_buckets()
```

try to get the details first then you can filter the details according to your need.

Creation_date is one of the property of s3 bucket which stores the date of creation  of that particular bucket.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `s3_bucket`? is that String? Check my code.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name='ap-northeast-2')
s3 = session.resource('s3')

if s3.Bucket('seoul-dev-datalake').creation_date:
    print(s3.Bucket('my-bucket-name').name, 'Done')
```

It gives the correct result.

```
my-bucket-name Done
```